# Python Summarizing data efficiently using loops in pandas

Tags: python, loops, pandas

Let say I have a dataset separated into years from 2005-2013

```
df = pd.read_csv('adj.csv')
```

with columns "Incident", "Vector", "Year", ...etc

I want the data separated by year and then the same function(pivot) is applied to each data set. Right now to produce a summary I am writing out code like this:

```
df2005=df[df['Year'] == 2005]
df2006=df[df['Year'] == 2006]
df2007=df[df['Year'] == 2007]
df2008=df[df['Year'] == 2008]
df2009=df[df['Year'] == 2009]
df2010=df[df['Year'] == 2010]
df2011=df[df['Year'] == 2011]
df2012=df[df['Year'] == 2012]
df2013=df[df['Year'] == 2013]

p2005=df2005.pivot_table(columns='Incident', index='Vector',
                             aggfunc=len,)
p2006=df2006.pivot_table(columns='Incident', index='Vector',
                             aggfunc=len,)
p2007=df2007.pivot_table(columns='Incident', index='Vector',
                             aggfunc=len,)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this or shorten this process without copying and pasting code  `df20XX=df[df['Year'] == 20XX], p20XX=df20XX.pivot_table(columns='Incident', index='Vector', aggfunc=len,)` and changing the `XX` to the year?

Comment: You could just get the unique values, convert to a list and then enumerate over this to produce your pivots. So something like `vals = df.Year.unique()` then you can just iterate over this and append to a list the pivot tables or add to a dict or something similar

Comment: @EdChum you are a smart dude. But you need to put those smarts in the answer box!

Comment: @ccsv Just a suggestion.  How about skipping the separation and just make the Year part of the pivot_table?  For example: index=['Year','Vector']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like the following would satisfy your requirements:

```
# get an array of the unique year values
year_vals = df.Year.unique()
# create our dict
data_dict={}
# iterate for each year make a key and set the value to the pivot table
for year in year_vals:
    data_dict[str(year)] = df[df.Year == year].pivot_table(columns='Incident', index='Vector',
                             aggfunc=len,)
```

You can then access any specific year in the dict like so:

```
# this retrieves the pivot table for 2012
data_dict['2012']
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of programming! If you EVER find yourself hard coding 'magic numbers' such as dates in your code, you're probably doing it wrong.

As @EdChum mentioned in the comments, one way to get around hard coded years is by iterating over a list.

Your question gives us no way to reproduce your challenge because you don't provide us any data. So I'll make some up:

```
np.random.seed(1)
n = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'somedata' : np.random.normal(5,2,size=n),
                   'Year' : np.random.randint(10, size=n)})

print df.head()

   Year  somedata
0     2  8.248691
1     8  3.776487
2     9  3.943656
3     9  2.854063
4     9  6.730815
```

you can iterate over each year like this:

```
for year in df.Year.unique():
    print year
```

The more Pandas-esque way of doing this is by using `groupby()`. Here's an example:

```
 print df.groupby('Year').sum()


        somedata
Year            
0     566.042926
1     464.741896
2     481.299877
3     483.864814
4     448.654140
5     576.779496
6     495.640276
7     597.023765
8     456.119432
9     507.458331
```

You can write almost any function to work with `groupby()`. To learn more about this I highly recommend reading the excellent [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) about `groupby()`.

Comment: @JD_Long Thanks but I was trying find a way to store the pivots tables with the years.